# Form passing variable errors

Tags: php

I have a form here where it suppose to pass the variable to another page. However when I did on the next page.

```
echo $_POST['firstname'];
echo $_POST['lastname'];
echo $_POST['address'];
```

The variable seems to be empty. May I know what is the correct way to do this?

The said form :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="edit-profile.php" name="editform" id="editform"><br><br><br>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">First Name</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $fname;?>" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></div>   
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Last Name</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lname;?>" class="form-control"name="lastname" id="lastname" /></div>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Address</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $address;?>" class="form-control"name="address" id="address" /></div>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">City</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $city;?>" class="form-control"name="city" id="city" /></div>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Country</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $country;?>" class="form-control"name="country" id="country" /></div>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Postcode</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $postcode;?>" class="form-control"name="postcode" id="postcode" /></div>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Phone Number</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $phonenumber;?>" class="form-control"name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" /></div>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">School ID</span><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $schoolid;?>" class="form-control"name="schoolid" id="schoolid" /></div>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="javascript:;"  onclick="parentNode.submit();">Edit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Try adding a slash like, `/edit-profile.php`

Comment: And since you use bootstap and jquery therefore, there's no need to use inline javascript when you can take advantage of selectors and event listeners

Comment: @Scorpion I used ./edit-profile (as the file is not in the root folder and it still return back nothing sadly.

Also I just added jquery and bootstrap for layouting purpose, have yet to explore the usage of selectors and event listener.

Comment: tested it works fine, i got `firstname, lastname, and address`. using same page php and form

Comment: @kevinabelita gosh, then im not sure what I did wrong. since we both used the same code. Any idea?

Comment: Then type in `action` a full url where `edit-profile` location is, like `action="http://yourserver/stuff/edit-profile.php"` That will work

Comment: @Scorpion tried. Didnt work

Comment: here, works properly [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/troxJp), tested firstname, lastname, address

Comment: wow! Amazing! Try to `print_r($_REQUEST)` in `edit-profile.php` and submit the form. What it contains?

Comment: where is your submit button

Comment: @KedarB the OP used the anchor tag as a substitute to a submit button

Comment: @KedarB i use <a href> as button and used js to capture the click. used the same code on my login and it works, not this form tho so I'm stumped.

Comment: @Scorpion Array ( [firstname] => [lastname] => [address] => [city] => [country] => [postcode] => [phonenumber] => [schoolid] => )

Comment: The `<A>` element should go inside a block element. It's entirely possible that the `parentNode` is not what you expect. What happens if you replace the `onclick` attribute with `onclick="alert (parentNode)"` or `"alert (parentNode.submit)"`?